# #1320 - No RETURN found in FUNCTION MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I'm try create a function in mysql but
the error is: #1320 - No RETURN found in FUNCTION
Thanks for the help

```
DELIMITER $$  
CREATE FUNCTION `bascar20_GPCSAS`.`getPrice`(codRef integer(11), ultimoInventario varchar(50), fechaInicial varchar(50), fechaFinal varchar(50))
    RETURNS INT(11)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    
    CONTAINS SQL
    
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    
    COMMENT ''
    -- SET @codRef := 105;
    -- SET @ultimoInventario := "2016-10-31";
    -- SET @fechaInicial := '2016-11-01';
    -- SET @fechaFinal := '2016-11-30';
    
        SET @S := (SELECT IF(COUNT(*)=0,0,Saldo) FROM inventarios_finales WHERE FK_codigo_referencia = @codRef and fecha_inventario = @ultimoInventario AND FK_bodega = 1001); 
        SET @VU := (SELECT IF(COUNT(*)=0,0,valorUnitario) FROM inventarios_finales WHERE FK_codigo_referencia = @codRef and fecha_inventario = @ultimoInventario AND FK_bodega = 1001); 
        SET @VT := @S * @VU;    
    BEGIN
    
        DECLARE returnVal INT(11);  
    
        SELECT ROUND(T.precio,0) INTO returnVal
        FROM (
        SELECT  Fecha, referecia, Tipo, Cantidad, PrecioUnitario, IF(Tipo='EA'||Tipo='EM',(@S:=@S+Cantidad),(@S:=@S-Cantidad)) as SALDO ,IF(Tipo='EA'||Tipo='EM',(@VT:=@VT+(Cantidad*PrecioUnitario)),@VT:=@VT-(Cantidad*@VU)) as valortotal,IF(Tipo='EA'||Tipo='EM',@VU:=@VT/@S,@VU) as precio
        FROM documentos
        WHERE PrecioUnitario != 0 and Cantidad != 0 and Fecha BETWEEN @fechaInicial and @fechaFinal and NombreArticulo = @codRef and (Tipo = 'RM' or Tipo = 'EA' or Tipo = 'EM')
        ORDER BY Fecha
        ) T
        ORDER BY T.Fecha DESC
        LIMIT 1
    
        RETURN returnVal;
    END$$
```

the error is:

> ## 1320 - No RETURN found in FUNCTION

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's cause you are missing a `;` before the `RETURN` statement as pointed below from your posted code.

```
 .....<rest of code>.....
 ORDER BY Fecha
        ) T
        ORDER BY T.Fecha DESC
        LIMIT 1       <----------- Here

        RETURN returnVal;
```